# terminate called when getline is used

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when I am running -

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what():  basic_string::substr`
As suggested in this post(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) , to read a line in c++, we use `std::getline (std::cin,name);` My code is :

```
   int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        int num;
        getline(std::cin,s);
        string q= s.substr(0,3);
        num  =stoi(s.substr(4));
    }
```

When I run only this:

```
    string s;
    int num;
    getline(std::cin,s);
    string q= s.substr(0,3);
    num  =stoi(s.substr(4));
```

It works. I think I have to flush my cin buffer. What should be the best practice for these type of cases? Thanks in advance

Comment: Best practice for the `>>t` is to flush the input buffer after, e.g. via `ignore`. Best practice for the `substr` is to make sure of the string length first.

Comment: Yes and it works fine when just after the while loop, I write `std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);`. So every time should I write like this?  Isn't there any better approach?

Comment: Usually you only want to consume through the newline left after your formatted numeric input. `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` Discussed in-detail [in **this** question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction).